# Mongodb Aggregated group by multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb

How do I merge all the different arrays "AvgAggByGroup","FSByGroup" and "saByGroup" based on _id.al, _id.st and _id.lob ?

doc1.json

```
{"contractId":"11016710","scoreId":"SCORE_1632332012864957000","legacyContractId":"743291","contractScore":{"contractData":{"elgCheck":"P"},"aggregateScore":{"region":"Northeast UHN","state":"New York","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:33:47Z","riskScoreCard":[{"aggregateScore":31.666666666666668,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall","lineOfBusiness":"Employee and Individual","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:33:47Z","scoreAttribute":[{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131657000","attributeScore":75,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131679000","attributeScore":25,"srcAttributeName":"OFFICE LAB","attributeValue":"0"}]},{"aggregateScore":31.666666666666668,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall","lineOfBusiness":"Medicare and Retirement","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:33:47Z","scoreAttribute":[{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131657000","attributeScore":75,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131679000","attributeScore":25,"srcAttributeName":"OFFICE LAB","attributeValue":"0"}]},{"aggregateScore":31.666666666666668,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:33:47Z","scoreAttribute":[{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131657000","attributeScore":75,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131679000","attributeScore":25,"srcAttributeName":"OFFICE LAB","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131690000","attributeScore":25,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES","attributeValue":"0"}]},{"aggregateScore":31.666666666666668,"scoreType":"Contract","aggregationLevel":"overall","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:33:47Z"},{"aggregateScore":0,"scoreType":"PaymentTerm","aggregationLevel":"overall","scoreAttribute":[{"attributeScore":0,"srcAttributeName":"Parity to BIC","attributeValue":"N/A"}]}]}}}
```

Doc2.json

```
{"contractId":"10154234","scoreId":"SCORE_1632332239343774000","legacyContractId":"631829","contractScore":{"contractData":{"elgCheck":"P"},"aggregateScore":{"region":"Northeast UHN","state":"New York","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:37:38Z","riskScoreCard":[{"aggregateScore":24.166666666666668,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall","lineOfBusiness":"Employee and Individual","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:37:38Z","scoreAttribute":[{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131657000","attributeScore":56.25,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131679000","attributeScore":18.75,"srcAttributeName":"OFFICE LAB","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131690000","attributeScore":56.25,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES","attributeValue":"0"}]},{"aggregateScore":0,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall","lineOfBusiness":"Medicare and Retirement","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:37:38Z","scoreAttribute":[{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131657000","attributeScore":56.25,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131679000","attributeScore":18.75,"srcAttributeName":"OFFICE LAB","attributeValue":"0"}]},{"aggregateScore":36.25,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:37:38Z","scoreAttribute":[{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131657000","attributeScore":56.25,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131679000","attributeScore":18.75,"srcAttributeName":"OFFICE LAB","attributeValue":"0"},{"scoreCardRiskAttributeId":"SCR_CW_ID_1631040185131690000","attributeScore":56.25,"srcAttributeName":"MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES","attributeValue":"0"}]},{"aggregateScore":36.25,"scoreType":"Contract","aggregationLevel":"overall","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T17:37:38Z"},{"aggregateScore":0,"scoreType":"PaymentTerm","aggregationLevel":"overall","scoreAttribute":[{"attributeScore":0,"srcAttributeName":"Parity to BIC","attributeValue":"N/A"},{"attributeScore":0,"srcAttributeName":"PPR","attributeValue":"N/A"}]}]}}}
```

Doc3.json

```
{"contractId":"10171104","scoreId":"SCORE_1632332586368887000","legacyContractId":"802437","contractScore":{"contractData":{"elgCheck":"P"},"aggregateScore":{"region":"Central UHN","state":"Texas","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T18:42:13Z","riskScoreCard":[{"aggregateScore":0,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall","lineOfBusiness":"Employee and Individual"},{"aggregateScore":0,"scoreType":"SCR","aggregationLevel":"overall"},{"aggregateScore":0,"scoreType":"Contract","aggregationLevel":"overall","riskScoredDate":"2021-09-22T18:42:13Z"},{"aggregateScore":0,"scoreType":"PaymentTerm","aggregationLevel":"overall","scoreAttribute":[{"attributeScore":0,"srcAttributeName":"Renewal Increase - compared to BIC trend","attributeValue":"N/A"},{"attributeScore":0,"srcAttributeName":"CMS Base","attributeValue":"N/A"}]}]}}}
```

facet query:

.aggregate([{"$match":{"$and":[{"contractScore.contractData.elgCheck":"P"}]}},{"$project":{"contractId":"$contractId","scoreId":"$scoreId","legacyContractId":"$legacyContractId","aggregateScore":"$contractScore.aggregateScore"}},{"$unwind":{"path":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard"}},{"$facet":{"AvgOverallAggByGroup":[{"$group":{"_id":{"state":"$aggregateScore.state","region":"$aggregateScore.region","aggregationLevel":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.aggregationLevel","scoreType":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.scoreType","lineOfBusiness":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.lineOfBusiness"},"AvgOverallAgg":{"$avg":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.aggregateScore"}}}],"scoreAttributesByGroup":[{"$group":{"_id":{"state":"$aggregateScore.state","region":"$aggregateScore.region","aggregationLevel":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.aggregationLevel","scoreType":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.scoreType","lineOfBusiness":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.lineOfBusiness"},"scoreAttributessss":{"$push":"$aggregateScore.riskScoreCard.scoreAttribute"}}},{"$addFields":{"scoreAttributessss":{"$reduce":{"input":"$scoreAttributessss","initialValue":[],"in":{"$setUnion":["$$value","$$this"]}}}}},{"$unwind":{"path":"$scoreAttributessss"}},{"$group":{"_id":{"state":"$_id.state","region":"$_id.region","aggregationLevel":"$_id.aggregationLevel","scoreType":"$_id.scoreType","lineOfBusiness":"$_id.lineOfBusiness","srcAttributeName":"$scoreAttributessss.srcAttributeName"},"avgScoreAttributeScore":{"$avg":"$scoreAttributessss.attributeScore"}}},{"$project":{"_id":{"state":"$_id.state","region":"$_id.region","aggregationLevel":"$_id.aggregationLevel","scoreType":"$_id.scoreType","lineOfBusiness":"$_id.lineOfBusiness"},"scoreAttribute":{"srcAttributeName":"$_id.srcAttributeName","attributeScore":"$avgScoreAttributeScore"}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","scoreAttribute":{"$push":"$scoreAttribute"}}}]}},{"$addFields":{"AvgOverallAggByGroup":{"$map":{"input":"$AvgOverallAggByGroup","as":"a","in":{"_id":"$$a._id","AvgOverallAgg":"$$a.AvgOverallAgg","scoreAttribute":{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$map":{"input":{"$filter":{"input":"$scoreAttributesByGroup","as":"s","cond":{"$and":[{"$eq":["$$s._id.scoreType","$$a._id.scoreType"]},{"$eq":["$$s._id.lineOfBusiness","$$a._id.lineOfBusiness"]}]}}},"as":"s","in":"$$s.scoreAttribute"}},0.0]}}}}}},{"$facet":{"Cards":[{"$project":{"AvgOverallAggByGroup":"$AvgOverallAggByGroup"}},{"$unwind":{"path":"$AvgOverallAggByGroup"}},{"$group":{"_id":"$AvgOverallAggByGroup._id.state","riskCards":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}}]}}],{"allowDiskUse":false});

desired output:

```
{ "Cards" : [ { "_id" : "New York", "riskCards" : [ { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "New York", "region" : "Northeast UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "SCR" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 33.958333333333336, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "CLINICAL LABORATORY", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "IMMUNIZATIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LAB - PATHOLOGY", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "cmsYear", "attributeScore" : 75.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "OFFICE LAB", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Site of Service Price Differential", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Default Percent of Eligible Charges", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES-SALINE & DEXTROSE SOLUTIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - IMMUNIZATION ADMINISTRATION", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Professional/Technical Modifier Pricing", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Calculation of Anesthesia Partial Units", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "DME & SUPPLIES", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES - IVIG", "attributeScore" : 25.0 } ] } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "New York", "region" : "Northeast UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "SCR", "lineOfBusiness" : "Employee and Individual" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 27.916666666666668, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "Default Percent of Eligible Charges", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "DME & SUPPLIES", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES - IVIG", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "OFFICE LAB", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES-SALINE & DEXTROSE SOLUTIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "CLINICAL LABORATORY", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - IMMUNIZATION ADMINISTRATION", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "cmsYear", "attributeScore" : 75.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Professional/Technical Modifier Pricing", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "IMMUNIZATIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Site of Service Price Differential", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Calculation of Anesthesia Partial Units", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LAB - PATHOLOGY", "attributeScore" : 0.0 } ] } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "New York", "region" : "Northeast UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "SCR", "lineOfBusiness" : "Medicare and Retirement" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 15.833333333333334, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "Calculation of Anesthesia Partial Units", "attributeScore" : 21.875 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "OFFICE LAB", "attributeScore" : 21.875 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN", "attributeScore" : 65.625 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "IMMUNIZATIONS", "attributeScore" : 40.625 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Site of Service Price Differential", "attributeScore" : 21.875 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "DME & SUPPLIES", "attributeScore" : 21.875 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES - IVIG", "attributeScore" : 21.875 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "cmsYear", "attributeScore" : 40.625 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES-SALINE & DEXTROSE SOLUTIONS", "attributeScore" : 40.625 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - IMMUNIZATION ADMINISTRATION", "attributeScore" : 65.625 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Default Percent of Eligible Charges", "attributeScore" : 21.875 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Professional/Technical Modifier Pricing", "attributeScore" : 21.875 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "CLINICAL LABORATORY", "attributeScore" : 40.625 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES", "attributeScore" : 40.625 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LAB - PATHOLOGY", "attributeScore" : 21.875 } ] } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "New York", "region" : "Northeast UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "PaymentTerm" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 0.0, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "Renewal Increase - compared to BIC trend", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "PPR", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "PBC Strategy", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "CMS Base", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Overall impact compared to BIC trend", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Parity to BIC", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Mid-Level Fee Differential Schedule", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Cost relativity to peers (aggregate)", "attributeScore" : 0.0 } ] } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "New York", "region" : "Northeast UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "Contract" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 33.958333333333336 } } ] }, { "_id" : "Texas", "riskCards" : [ { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "Texas", "region" : "Central UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "SCR", "lineOfBusiness" : "Employee and Individual" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 17.333333333333336, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "Default Percent of Eligible Charges", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "DME & SUPPLIES", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES - IVIG", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "OFFICE LAB", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES-SALINE & DEXTROSE SOLUTIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "CLINICAL LABORATORY", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - IMMUNIZATION ADMINISTRATION", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "cmsYear", "attributeScore" : 75.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Professional/Technical Modifier Pricing", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "IMMUNIZATIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Site of Service Price Differential", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Calculation of Anesthesia Partial Units", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LAB - PATHOLOGY", "attributeScore" : 0.0 } ] } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "Texas", "region" : "Central UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "SCR" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 17.333333333333336, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "CLINICAL LABORATORY", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "IMMUNIZATIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LAB - PATHOLOGY", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "cmsYear", "attributeScore" : 75.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "OFFICE LAB", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Site of Service Price Differential", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Default Percent of Eligible Charges", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES-SALINE & DEXTROSE SOLUTIONS", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - IMMUNIZATION ADMINISTRATION", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - CHEMO ADMIN", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Professional/Technical Modifier Pricing", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Calculation of Anesthesia Partial Units", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "DME & SUPPLIES", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "MEDICINE - PHYSICAL MED AND REHAB - MODALITIES", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "INJECTABLES - IVIG", "attributeScore" : 25.0 } ] } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "Texas", "region" : "Central UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "PaymentTerm" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 0.0, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "Renewal Increase - compared to BIC trend", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "PPR", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "PBC Strategy", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "CMS Base", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Overall impact compared to BIC trend", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Parity to BIC", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Mid-Level Fee Differential Schedule", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "Cost relativity to peers (aggregate)", "attributeScore" : 0.0 } ] } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "Texas", "region" : "Central UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "Contract" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 12.453508771929824 } }, { "AvgOverallAggByGroup" : { "_id" : { "state" : "Texas", "region" : "Central UHN", "aggregationLevel" : "overall", "scoreType" : "language" }, "AvgOverallAgg" : 9.467105263157896, "scoreAttribute" : [ { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Credentialing", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Payer_Benefit_Plans", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Consequences_for_failure_to_adhere", "attributeScore" : 8.25 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Definitions_Payer", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Electronic_Connectivity", "attributeScore" : 33.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_New_Medical_Group_Professionals", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Payment_of_Claims_for_Covered_Services_Fee_Schedule_change", "attributeScore" : 25.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Correction_of_Claims_payments_Medical_Group_will_repay", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Dispute_Resolution_Clause2", "attributeScore" : 14.4375 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Assignment", "attributeScore" : 18.75 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Liability_Insurance", "attributeScore" : 24.75 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Correction_of_Claims_payments_Recovery_of_overpayments", "attributeScore" : 12.375 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Retroactive_Correction_of_information", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Electronic_Filing_Of_Claims", "attributeScore" : 10.3125 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Payment_Of_Claims", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Intro_Effective_Date", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Maintenance_of_and_Access_to_Records", "attributeScore" : 0.0 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Correction_of_Claims_payments", "attributeScore" : 16.5 }, { "srcAttributeName" : "LA_Access_to_data", "attributeScore" : 16.5 } ] } } ] } ] }
```

Comment: give some data in and expected output also if you can, so we test the code

Comment: added the requests and desired output data. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: have you checked [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) ? its like running multiple pipelines with input 1 pipeline. maybe can help, each pipeline result become 1 new field, maybe can help

Comment: sure. i have not..but i can check.Let me do some research and let you know.

Comment: I am able to use the $facet. but not able to combine multiple arrays into a single array.

Comment: check `$concatArrays`, in case you have arrays insidde 1 array check also `$reduce` , if  you are stuck if you can give the data from where you stopped, and the expected data

Comment: Hello @takis, the data (doc1 and doc2) and desired output is already there in the main question.  Comment has characters limitations.

Comment: i tried long time now, sorry : ( for not helping you,  data got me confused, maybe its not hard what you want to do , i hope you will solve it, or someone else will help you,

Comment: No worries and thank you for trying and helping me to reach at this point.  I can Google and see how I can merge multiple arrays  of objects and make it flat array.

Comment: Hello Takis, i am able to get the final output but my query became very lengthy. I dont know if it is possible for you to review and improve anywhere? Please let me know if it is feasible for you. Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: if its fast enough, i think its ok, if you want post it here with the samlple data, and we will see(actually i helped you so little bad ok), maybe other people can help also

Comment: Sure. thank you. I have added the request, query and output. hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: Hello Takis, please let me know if there is any scope for improvement on the above facet query.

Comment: Hello Vinnet i gave up on this, the last time i tried and i was confused :( , hope you have solved it by now.